# "Error getting chaincode package bytes" when deploying chaincode on hyperledger via REST

Tags: ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to deploy chaincode on hyperledger (Bluemix service) via POST/REST to

/chaincode
QuerySpec

> { "jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "deploy", "params": { "type": 1,
>   "chaincodeID": { "path":
>   "https://github.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/tree/master/finished"
>   }, "ctorMsg": { "function": "init", "args": [ "hi there" ] },
>   "secureContext": "user_type1_0" }, "id": 1 }

I've also tried those links

https://github.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/blob/master/finished/chaincode_finished?raw=true

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/master/finished/chaincode_finished.go

I always get

> {   "jsonrpc": "2.0",   "error": {
>       "code": -32001,
>       "message": "Deployment failure",
>       "data": "Error when deploying chaincode: Error getting chaincode package bytes: Error getting code 'go get' failed with error: 'exit
>   status 1'\npackage
>   github.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/tree/master/finished: cannot
>   find package
>   'github.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/tree/master/finished' in any
>   of:\n\t/usr/local/go/src/github.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/tree/master/finished
>   (from
>   $GOROOT)\n\t/go/*usercode*/552962906/src/github.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/tree/master/finished
>   (from
>   $GOPATH)\n\t/go/src/github.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/tree/master/finished\n"
>   },   "id": 1 }

Any idea?

Comment: I'm getting this issue trying to deploy v1.0 and v2.0. Did you get this solved in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Considering that you are playing with Bluemix service, I assume you are following ["Implementing your first chain code tutorial"](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/blockchain/ibmblockchain_tutorials.html#hellocc)

If your forked repository you will see instructions to use branch v1.0 for Bluemix Blockchain Services ([link](https://github.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/tree/v1.0#versions-and-supported-platforms)) IBM BMX Service is (still) using Fabric v0.5.

Once you have Registered with one of the available Enroll ID you should be able to deploy your chaincode using **DeploySpec** (note the path: "`https://github.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/tree/v1.0/finished`")

```
{
"jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "method": "deploy",
  "params": {
    "type": 1,
    "chaincodeID": {
      "path": "https://github.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/tree/v1.0/finished"
    },
    "ctorMsg": {
      "function": "init",
      "args": [
        "hi there"
      ]
    },
    "secureContext": "user_type1_0"
  },
  "id": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all deploy command should be changed to ( the value for path variable was changed):

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "deploy",
    "params": {
        "type": 1,
        "chaincodeID": {
            "path": "https://github.com/romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/finished"
        },
        "ctorMsg": {
            "function": "init",
            "args": ["hi there"]
        },
        "secureContext": "user_type1_0"
    },
    "id": 1
}
```

**P.S.** As @Mil4n correctly mentioned, IBM Bluemix still works with Fabric v0.5. Chaincode `romeokienzler/learn-chaincode/finished` should be adopted to this version.

For example `shim.ChaincodeStubInterface` is not available yet and should be replaced with `*shim.ChaincodeStub`.

Comment: He is using IBM BMX Services which is using the chaincode from his repository, why does it matter if the path exists locally for this issue?

Comment: @Mil4n  Good point. My answer was for local environment instead of Bluemix. Now it’s updated. Thank you!